# TypeError: Cannot read property 'html5Mode'

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

this is my route.js config file of routing

```
export default routesConfig;


function routesConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  $stateProvider
    .state('login', {
      url: '/',
      component: 'login'
    })
    .state('home', {
      abstract: true,
      url: '/home',
      component: 'home'
    })
}
```

and in my app.js

```
angular.module('app', [
  uiRouter,
  Login,
  Home
])
  .config(['$locationProvider'],routesConfig())

  .component('app', AppComponent);
```

Login and Home are two module each module had a component assiciated with it.

Comment: Did you try without the `hashPrefix` ?

Comment: In your `app.js` file, can you add `$locationProvider` as an argument when calling `routesConfig()`?

Comment: and that should be third argument.

Comment: @DeendayalGarg - sure, the link should be: `.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider'],routesConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider))`

Answer (score 1):

Problem here is you are not specifying dependency parameters required by function in same order.

You must have to inject the argument in the same order as in function definition.

So in your app.js you have to specify injection parameter in same order.

```
angular.module('app', [
   uiRouter, 
   Login,  
   Home
])
.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider','$locationProvider'],routesConfig)

.component('app', AppComponent);
```